# one-to-one or one-to-many: one table with hundred columns or moving columns to an extra table

Tags: sql, postgresql, symfony, database-design, doctrine-orm

i am trying to find the best DB design for the following problem.

i have 20000 data sets which look like this:

```
1. id, name, color, width, xxxx ... 150 attributes
2. id, name, color, width, xxxx ... 150 attributes
3. ...
```

which means that i have 20000 entities and 150 attributes like color, width etc for each one of them.

i need all these attributes and maybe 15 are being used more than others. this is being used in a web application and it has to perform.

solutions i thought about:

1. normalized two tables approach:

   - id, name and a few "more important" attributes in one main table
   - in another table (one-to-one relation): id and other less important attributes, every one of the in different column
2. everything in one monster table:

   - id, name, color, width ...
3. normalized two table approach (one-to-many):

   - main table with: id and name
   - in another table (one-to-many relation): other table with: id, attr_name, value

i like [3] most but i am not sure is this going to perform if i need a lot of data because every "id" has 150 values. and i would have to things like

```
SELECT mt.id, mt.name, at.attr_name, at.value
FROM main_table mt
INNER JOIN attr_table at ON at.id = mt.id
     AND at.attr_name IN ('width', 'color', 'a', 'b', 'c' .....)
     AND at.id IN (1,3,9...)
ORDER BY 1
```

having maybe 15-20 different values in "attr_name IN (...)" does not look optimal. and if i need 10-30 different datasets (which i usually do), it looks even less appealing.

output of this would be probably 200-300 lines and I would have to normalize this output in the code.

[2] is pretty dirty and simple but i am not sure how does it perform. and having 150 columns in one monster table also does not look optimal.

i like on this approach that i can do a lot of stuff in sql and not later in code like: attr1 - attr2 ... (like "max_width - width" or weight - max_weight/4).

[1] i don't like this one because it does not look clean to have "some" attributes in one table and all other attributes of the same type in an another

What is the best solution for this specific problem?

I found some similar but not same questions:
[Best to have hundreds of columns or split into multiple tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428243/best-to-have-hundreds-of-columns-or-split-into-multiple-tables)
[Is it better to have many columns, or many tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23939357/is-it-better-to-have-many-columns-or-many-tables)

Comment: First, 150 columns is not that many and should be easily handled by the database.  Second, database layouts should be designed around usage.  What types of queries will be run?  How often are updates performance?  How much new data is being inserted?

Comment: 4. Use `HSTORE` or `JSON` to store 150 attributes in one table column as key:value pairs. With proper indexing you will be able to query them easily.

Comment: @GordonLinoff basicly only SELECTs.

Comment: As for 3-rd solution - google [`EAV`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model). It has all its pros and cons described.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko i have to be able to search through it and it should perform because it is for a web application.

Comment: @user0001 Postgres 9.3+ can query values inside `JSON` (or `HSTORE` or `XML`). And postgres 9.4+ can index this values efficiently for good query speed.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko as i described in question (added later), if I use EAV, i will have to reorder everything in code which probably does not perform if i have to do it every time for 200-300 lines which are returned from the database

Comment: As others are saying, the database should be able to handle this *small* amount of data easily and be performant.  The question I ask is exactly what performance problems are u experiencing, please give details.  Anticipating issues isn't useful unless you know at what point they really occur

Comment: ordering can be addressed with indexes.

Comment: key-value stores are attractive but the community knowledge available is far less than SQL

Comment: @MichaelDurrant I am just trying to be prepared for everything :). So you are saying that I should use one "big" table with 150 columns?

Answer (score 0):

With so few rows as 20,000 I would have no doubt about going full normalized. In my opinion even with much more rows I would still do it in instead of the additional JSON's full new set of problems and weaknesses.

*output of this would be probably 200-300 lines and I would have to normalize this output in the code*

Create a view to not have to do the join at every query

```
create view the_view as
select id, mt.name, at.attr_name, at.value
from
    main_table mt
    inner join
    attr_table at using (id)
```

Filter when selecting

```
select *
from the_view
where
    attr_name = 'color' and "value" = 'red'
    and
    attr_name = 'width' and "value" = '30'
    and
    id in (1, 3, 9)
```

150 columns suggest that the attributes list is not stable. If you create a table with 150 columns you will have to be always altering the table to add new columns. The normalized approach is flexible. You create attributes at will simple by adding a row to a table.

There should be 3 tables; `main_table`, `main_table_attr_table` and `attr_table`. The `main_table_attr_table` is a n to n connection between the other two.

Comment: why is this approach better than one table with 150 columns?

Comment: thanks. I am trying json and a full normalized way. i will report back which was best for me. i can only say that json is nice but even indexed not very fast.